# GCP API format of disk image is incorrect

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

Trying to spin up a VM through the GCP API.

Keep getting

```
Message[Invalid value for field 'resource.disks[0].initializeParams.sourceImage': 'projects/windows-cloud/global/images/windows-2016/windows-server-2016-dc-v20190108'. The URL is malformed.] Location[ - ] Reason[invalid] Domain[global]
```

Just want a windows 2008 image as the disk.

How should the format be? Can't seem to get it to work, tried several variants.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the images using

```
gcloud compute images list --uri
```

it was

```
projects/windows-cloud/global/images/windows-server-2008-r2-dc-v20190108
```

Answer (score 1):

You can no longer access images from `projects/**` otherwise you'll get a URL malformed error.

To see all the list of images, you need to run the command:

```
gcloud compute images list --uri --project=<project-id>
```

If you want to see the complete url of a particular image family, you need to run the following command:

```
gcloud compute images describe-from-family rocky-linux-8-optimized-gcp --zone=us-central1-a --project=rocky-linux-cloud
```

The correct URL is in the `selfLink` field value